# Is there a way to update Firestore before window refresh or window close in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

Rather than updating Firestore each time a user updates a value, I'd like to store all changes in an object and update all changes all at once.
I got this part working when for example a save button is pressed.

But what can I do when the user closes the window or refreshes it.
This could or could not be a way to do this without a framework

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  console.log('You are about to refresh')
}
```

I am however using Vue.js and don't know if there is a solution to this problem.

So what I am looking for is a way to run a method before the page refreshes or the window is closed.

Comment: So you're saying you want to make the end user wait for the browser window to close refresh while your code performs some work that might or might not finish?  That sounds like a bad UX, and I wouldn't be surprised if browsers didn't allow this.

Comment: Sound reasonable, can you think of a way to tackle this problem? Rather than writing to Firestore on each value change?

Comment: Write to local storage?

Comment: Thanks Doug, I will have a look at it

Comment: Use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API in combination with the firestore REST API. That's what I did and it worked reliably.